# Nginx case insensitive URL and rewrite URL?

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx configured as reverse proxy

```
 server {
 listen 80;
 server_name   www.pluto.com;
 location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 }
}
```

I need that the URL request from any combination of FOLDER1 (case insensitive) is rewrite from URL

```
http://www.pippo.com/FOLDER1/etc..etc..etc..
```

to (always lowercase folder1)

```
http://127.0.0.1/folder1/etc..etc..etc...
```

where **etc..etc..etc**. = anything that I need to keep

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~* ^/folder1(?:/?)(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/folder1/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

`(?:/?)` says we may have one slash after `folder1` which in that case we just ignore it. we then grab whatever remains by `(.*)` which will be placed in `$1`. then in the `proxy_pass` argument, we build the new URI: first we add what we had after `folder1/` in the original URI and then we add all the arguments. so if your original URI is `/folder1/test`, the `proxy_pass` URI should be `http://127.0.0.1:8080/folder1/test`. do some experiments with the cases where you have parameters, e.g. `/folder1/test?id=1`. I'm not sure whether `(.*)` will capture the `?id=1` part too or not. if it does, then the `proxy_pass` should be changed to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/folder1/$1`.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: It would probably be better to add your explanation to the answer itself (use the `edit` button below your answer), rather than explaining your answer in the comments.

Comment: Awesome answer I've been looking for this all day!